# Why is the question about arXiv not off-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I'm curious about why [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164905) about the popularity of arXiv among statisticians is not off-topic.

In full disclosure, I flagged it as off-topic and the flag was declined. To me, this decision, along with the numerous up-votes, indicates that the question is -- by moderator and popular consensus -- on topic. I'm fine with that and I get the connection to arXiv and its importance within the scientific community which obviously includes statisticians. But doesn't that mean that a question about the popularity of Scottish meat pies or Celine Dion among statisticians could also be on topic? Slippery slope and all that...

Maybe it should be a "Community Wiki" question like [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89376) about having to learn SAS before practicing statistics in the private sector?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was a tough call.

CW tends to be used here for questions likely to generate useful and interesting replies, but where no single objectively best reply seems possible.  It might also be applied to questions of a rapidly evolving nature (if such questions are deemed so important that they shouldn't be closed).

In the case of the arXiv question, it was posed in a way that at least seemed to allow the possibility of a unique objectively valid answer that would be permanently useful.  (Nevertheless, when I first saw it I paused over the "close" button for a long time.)  I was delighted that several such answers have since appeared, differing only in the evidence they use to support their common conclusion.